# What hardware and sensor do I need to install Android 4.4 in Raspberry Pi 2 or 3?

Tags: raspberry-pi, android

I'm working with [Sentiance SDK](https://developers.sentiance.com/docs/sdk/android/integration) in Android 
and I want to know if it's possible make a Raspberry with android that works with this SDK. For this reason, my question is, what hardware do I need?

Can Android on a Raspberry Pi connect to GPRS, gyroscope and SIM card hardware?

Comment: This is a good question. I don't know why is considered an off-topic, I want to install android on a raspberry pi so I can use the comfortability of adding and removing sensors on top of a raspberry pi